# Run and Debug a complete C project with Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, makefile, build

I'm trying to use a C project (with Makefile) in Xcode, with the main purpose of using the debugger on the project itself.

I performed the following steps taken from the following [site](https://medium.com/@acecilia/setup-a-c-c-makefile-project-in-xcode-syntax-highlight-autocompletion-jump-to-definition-and-80405bd4542e) site:

1. File -> New -> Project
2. Under the cross-platform tab, use the External Build System template. Give it a name and finish the setup:
3. Then, go to the info tab of the main target and change the directory to the one that contains Makefile

In the link above, he continues by saying to create a new target

4. File -> New -> Target
5. Under the macOS tab, use the Command Line Tool template. Give it a name, set the language and finish the setup.
6. Now we are going to drag the source code folder (I also import the import folder with the .h) to the Xcode project.
7. In the next screen, under the Add to targets section, make sure to mark the previously created target (the one created in step 4).

Now, if I run all the points except 4, 5, and 7 I get the same (incomplete) result.
The build works perfectly, building the object files, linking everything and building a working executive.
But .. I have no way to run the project. Also by pressing the play symbol at the top. It runs only the build.
Obviously as a result I have no way to use debugging and breackPoints.
My main goal.

Note that the Makefile file uses the -g flag.

Creating a simple xCode project with the Command-Line template set to C.
Where everything works perfectly I noticed the following thing:

[image]

The image above is the report of the project created with the template, I have builds in my project (the green part of template) but I miss debugging (the red part)

There are probably some settings in Building settings to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I succeeded:

Import into Xcode a complete C project (with source file and header), in which there is a Makefile responsible for creating the .o and the executive files.

This the graph of the project:

```
                                   PrjDir/
                                      |   
          +-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
          |                   |                   |                   |                   |
         bin/                 src/                include/            build/            xcodeDir/
          |                   |                    |                  |                   |
         exe                  file.c              file.h      Makefile output/          tA.xcodeproj
                                                                        |                    
                                                                      file.o
```

All the steps described in the site put in the question above must be performed.

Now to understand:

We call the first Target 'tA', the one created using the "External Build System" template (this is also the name of the Xcode project).

And 'tB' the one created with the "Command Line Tool" template (point 4 above).

We have to modify the schema of 'tA' so that the executable refers to the target 'tB'.
[image]

Then you have to go to the 'tB' "Build Settings", write in the search "other c" and in the "Other C Flags" panel enter: "I-completePath/PrjDir/include/"
[image]

Run and build, also with breakpoint inserted in any point of any file.

Everything works as expected!!